# Automatically generate a response to a powershell command?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-7

I am executing a powershell script i.e commands in a `ps1` file. To run any powershell script on a system, you have to first run `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` and then ENTER `y` manually. Only after that, you can run ps scripts. Is there a way I can automatically enter `y` along with the command to enable powershell scripts ?

Demo:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

Execution Policy Change
The execution policy helps protect you from scripts that you do not trust. 
Changing the execution policy might expose you to the security risks described 
in the about_Execution_Policies help topic. Do you want to change the execution 
policy? [Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

Comment: you can define the policy when lauching the console : `powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -noexit`

Comment: @Kayasax - thanks for your answer. Since I am new to powershell, can you please tell me what the command means ? Please consider adding it as an answer after that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

you can set the executionpolicy for the current session when you start the shell like this :
`powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -noexit`

Quoted from the [doc](http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-FR/library/hh847748.aspx) :

> SET A DIFFERENT EXECUTION POLICY FOR ONE SESSION
>
> ---

```
You can use the ExecutionPolicy parameter of PowerShell.exe to
set an execution policy for a new Windows PowerShell session.
The policy affects only the current session and child sessions.

To set the execution policy for a new session, start Windows PowerShell
at the command line (such as Cmd.exe or Windows PowerShell), and then use
the ExecutionPolicy parameter of PowerShell.exe to set the execution
policy.

For example:
```

PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy AllSigned

```
The execution policy that you set is not stored in the registry.
Instead, it is stored in the $env:PSExecutionPolicyPreference
environment variable. The variable is deleted when you close
the session in which the policy is set. You cannot change the
policy by editing the variable value.


During the session, the execution policy that is set for the session takes
precedence over an execution policy that is set in the registry for the 
local computer or current user. However, it does not take precedence over 
the execution policy set by using a Group Policy setting (discussed below).
```